# After changing the "Price Class" in "CloudFront" the change has no effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I changed the *Price Class* of an Amazon CloudFront distribution, but even after a few days it continues to pass traffic to regions that are no longer listed.

Do I need to do something for the change to take effect?

Comment: It sounds like what you are describing might be normal behavior, so let's clarify: please give a specific example of something you see happening that you don't expect to be happening after changing the price class.

Answer (score 0):

The **Price Class** can be used to restrict the locations from which Amazon CloudFront **serves** traffic. The location determines the charge for outbound data.

A common practice to reduce CloudFront costs is to use a more restrictive price class because Internet data is cheaper from the USA and Europe.

If your goal is to **restrict** where traffic is served, you can instead choose to [Restrict the Geographic Distribution of Your Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html), which lets you control which countries can (or cannot) receive traffic from Amazon CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

Price class can limit distribution regions saving on delivery cost if you are willing to compromise performance.

Even if you set a limiting price class (Eg. only US, Canada and Europe) CloudFront may occasionally serve requests from an edge location in a region that is not included in your price class - when this happens you will be charged by the least expensive region in your price class.

[See here for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PriceClass.html)